# Android Custom font shows up blank on some phones

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font

I'm using a custom font for a Japanese quiz app on Android. I tried it on a friend's phone at a cookout, and the font did not show up (it shows up on mine and others). The font is delivered with the apk.  I don't have access to the logcat, and unfortunately forgot to check the phone model, although I think it's kind of a budget version. Has anyone had this problem this, or have any ideas what might cause it?

Comment: About absent logcat: when i faced with customer who can't use adb, we recommend use catlog ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat ) to retrieve logs from devices without desktop with android sdk installed.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you use delivered font with APK and got unexpected results, its generally rendering issue with Android system .. with other words, Android System cannot render all characters correctly. you need to know that earlier versions of Android don't support all Unicodes as well as later but off cause with more supported characters . if you want to test that on emulator, try to test your app with version 1.6.

I got similar issue with Arabic characters ..

I can help you with those guides:

1- try to check the characters you are using, and be away from rare characters.

2- try a different common font if its available.

3- If you built your own font, try to rebuild it again and use supported ID of glyphes. as I told you Android doesn't support all Unicode characters (supports based on ID). and its different from version to another.

4- check and detect unsupported characters ( you can do that by measuring length of character and compare it with pre-measured length of that character) then insert it as image with suitable dimension.

5-you can use webview instead of TextView/EditText ..

I hope that will help you ..

good luck,